# DELETE Query throws: Error 1062 Duplicate entry 'X-Y' for key; but no duplicates in table

Tags: mysql, duplicates, key

I have a composite unique key on two columns, "user_id" & "project_id".

When I try to run a DELETE query on single rows or multiple rows, I get an error.

```
ERROR 1062: 1062: Duplicate entry '87-1736' for key 'index_on_user_id_and_project_id'

SQL Statement:
DELETE FROM `members` WHERE `id`='39142'
```

The table has a single column primary key, 2 single column unique indexes (for user_id and project_id), and 1 composite unique index on user_id and project_id. No foreign keys in the database.

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `project_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `mail_notification` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_on_user_id_and_project_id` (`user_id`,`project_id`),
  KEY `index_members_on_user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `index_members_on_project_id` (`project_id`)
```

This error only shows up for certain entries (a lot of entries) and it is consistently those entries that are problematic (e.g. 87 and 1736 pair shown above).

I have tried looking for duplicates and none were found. I was able to find some entries in there with "0"s in the fields and I removed those entries. No NULL fields were found.

**I have tried:**

- looking for duplicates, found none.
- looking for zero or NULL values in the index fields, deleted, but did not solve
- removing the composite unique index, did not solve.
- `alter ignore table ... add unique index (user_id, project_id)`, it found no duplicates, threw a warning about IGNORE being deprecated, and did not solve

How do I delete these problematic entries?

Comment: In order to get a duplicate key error on a `delete`, you would need to have a trigger on the table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you so much for helping me find that. Totally forgot about the triggers. if you put that as an answer I would accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is impossible for a `delete` statement itself to generate a duplicate key error.  At least, I cannot think of any way for that to happen in an unbroken database.  After all, if you are *removing* a value, it can't conflict with another value.

That leaves the possibility that something else is going on.  The only reasonable alternative is a trigger on the table.  It is unfortunate that the error message doesn't specify the table name, but that is the only cause that I can readily think of.

Answer (score 2):

I've bumped into this before when I've had the target table (t1) tied to a history table (t1_hist). t1_hist was populated by a trigger on changes to the t1 (any add/change/delete). Once I deleted the unwanted records from the t1_hist, I was able to delete from the t1. This required a second pass delete from the t1_hist table because it recorded my deletes from t1.

Simply, mine was: DELETE FROM t1 WHERE customer_number > 50000;

Same error. Did the same from t1_hist first (and last), then no problem.